# Reordering paragraphs or other elements with css

Tags: css, css-float, css-grid

I have two layouts switching with a media query and I see that the picture occupying the top right hand quarter of my home page would be better off at the very end of the page, when on the mobile phone smaller layout. But my html (markdown, but that doesn't matter) has the figure element being first.
So what I would like would be absolute positioning, except it stays in the flow, no superposing. As if I had reordered the elements.
Javascript is forbidden, is there a simple way with css ?
Thanks.
the only thing I can think of now is duplicating the element and applying display:none on one or the other.

Comment: why don't you use the `order` property that works with grid and flexbox? Alternatively you can also use `grid-area` with CSS-Grid... All in combination with media queries...

Comment: It the image doesn't convey actual content just insert as a background of an element  (maybe a pseudolement?) and use mediaqueries to set the background. Otherwise flexbox position and order could help, but from an accessibility point of view, changing significantly the visual order of the elements is not a good idea

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I disagree. Setting an image as the background for styling purposes is not accessible at all. It sounds to me, that the basic layout is changed in mobile devices which is no issue for screen readers. especially if an image does not get focused in the first place or uses `aria-hidden` attribute

Comment: The alternative text of an image is read by assistive technologies. if the AT reads that text but the images is not even in the viewport could cause confusion to users.

An image should be set as a background, if it doesn't convey actual content (e.g. hero (stock) images, decorative images, separators...)

Sure you can use `aria-hidden`,  but if it has to be ignored by AT then you can place it as a background.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up with what tacosy suggested, here is an example of how you could do it with Flexbox or Grid.

HTML for my example

```
<div class="container">
  <figure>
    <!-- Your image here -->
  </figure>
  <div class="content">
    <!-- Your other content here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

With Flexbox

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  figure {
    order: 1;
  }

  .content {
    order: 0;
  }
}
```

Or with Grid

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "figure"
    "content";
}

figure {
  grid-area: figure;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-areas:
      "content"
      "figure";
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh I did think about that (not the order bit though, but the effect would be the same), and it eludes the biggest issue: **floating**. the picture in question is floating on the left and it is ignored on grid items. Nor in flex containers

Comment: Are you using an CSS framework like Bootstrap or Tailwind?

Comment: I use SASS. Mostly for variables $balbla and some mixins.